# Upgrading from liferay 6.0.6 to 6.2 failed

Tags: liferay

We planned to upgrade from liferay 6.0.6 to 6.2.
When we want to do that, we got an error.
So we tried to first upgrade to liferay 6.1 and then to 6.2.
We have successfully upgraded to liferay 6.1 but again when we want to upgrade from 6.1 to 6.2 we got the same error.
This is the error :

java.lang.IllegalStateException: The database contains changes from a previous upgrade attempt that failed. Please restore the old database and file system and retry the upgrade. A patch may be required if the upgrade failed due to a bug or an unforeseen data permutation that resulted from a corrupt database.

Comment: Did you try what the error message suggested?

Comment: yes, we did it.
But we again got the error.

Comment: With this limited information, I can only advise contacting Liferay support (if you're EE customer) or raise a JIRA ticket on issues.liferay.com

Comment: Can you paste the whole stacktrace, so that we know what failed? Also when the upgrade fails you would need to restore the previous database and then try the upgrade again on that database.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. This is because when you start an upgrade and somehow its abandoned midway, the database you are using becomes useless or in ILLEGAL State. 
Also you can upgrade from 6.0.6 to 6.2 in one step. And now that GA3 is out. I suggest you use that.
 
1. Create a new blank database say "newdb".
 2. Dump your old database into this "newdb"
 3. In your portal-ext.properties file of Liferay 6.2 bundle make it to point to this "newdb".
 4. Start the Liferay 6.2 server the upgrade should start.